# How to clone string type fields and why?

Tags: java, string, clone

Redefined `clone()` method to make a deep copy of an object. The object has a `String` field. How should I clone it correctly and why?

```java
public class Stepik_05_04_Clone {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {

        MyObj myObj1 = new MyObj();
        myObj1.i = 1;
        myObj1.s = "abc1";
        myObj1.innerObj.j = 2;

        MyObj myObj2 = myObj1.clone();
        myObj2.i = 10;
        myObj2.s = "abc2";
        myObj2.innerObj.j = 20;

        System.out.println(myObj1.i);
        System.out.println(myObj1.s);
        System.out.println(myObj1.innerObj.j);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(myObj2.i);
        System.out.println(myObj2.s);
        System.out.println(myObj2.innerObj.j);

    }
}

class MyObj implements Cloneable {
    int i;
    String s;
    InnerObj innerObj = new InnerObj();

    @Override
    protected MyObj clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        MyObj myObj = (MyObj)super.clone();
        myObj.innerObj = innerObj.clone();
        return myObj;
    }
}

class InnerObj implements Cloneable{
    int j;

    @Override
    protected InnerObj clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return (InnerObj)super.clone();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a test question for you to answer, which means they taught you the answer, so you should (re)read the Java learning material you have to find the answer. We can answer for you, but then you'll learn nothing.

Comment: if String immutable do I need to write something extra in clone()? Maybe in terms of performance, because are we dealing with a String pool? I am confused that the String is a reference data type!

Comment: Just read the documentation of [clone()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#clone()): "*...Typically, this means copying any **mutable** objects... If a class contains only primitive fields or references to **immutable** objects, then it is usually the case that **no fields** in the object returned by super.clone need to be modified.,,,*"

Comment: Carlos, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You are only dealing with primitives and `immutable` objects here - `String` is such, so no need to worry about `clone` in this case; it will work just fine. In general, clone is a pretty terrible idea and can get very complicated unless you truly understand what it does. To better visualize how broken it can get, just comment the `myObj.innerObj = innerObj.clone();` line and add one more output line:

```
System.out.println(myObj2.innerObj.j);
System.out.println(myObj1.innerObj.j);
```

Can you explain to yourself why you would get an output of `20, 20`?